# Cordova has two timeouts if a Url does not load

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am building an application built on Cordova 5.2.0 codebase. I notice that when attempting to load an invalid URL two timeouts seem to occur. The first occurs in `CordovaWebViewImpl` after about 20 seconds:

[image]

About a minute or two later an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error is captured in the `onReceivedError` method of my `SystemWebViewClient` instance.

[image]

My question basically is why there are two different timeouts and how are these timeout values set? Ideally I would actually want a single timeout being triggered in the `SystemWebViewClient`, but I guess I could just ignore the first one (`CordovaWebViewImpl`) if I could control the timeout for the second (`SystemWebViewClient`).

Comment: Are you using and index.html or an url?

Comment: I am using a Url to an external server. I am porting my code from a previous version which used Cordova 3.5.0. The idea is that if something goes wrong in loading the content the application must just bring up a settings dialog to enter the correct server details. In Cordova 3.5.0 CordovaWebView was actually a subclass of Webview and I could just capture the timeout in the onReceivedError method. In Cordova 5.2.0 CordovaWebView is now an interface and error handling seems more complicated.

Comment: Well, I'm having the same issue.. I can not even load google...

Comment: You need these entries in the config.xml in res/xml folder of your project: <access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />

Comment: If you aren't reading the config.xml in your custom application then look for shouldInterceptRequest  method of SystemWebViewClient and make it simply return null. Then you should be able to load google. If this does not help then maybe make a separate question on stackoverflow outlining your problem and giving some code.

Comment: Nothing of those idead worked. It's weird because in the older version everything works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89427/discussion-between-azrael94-and-brucehill).